# Можно ли указать стиль шрифта для всего приложения?

Tags: java, android

Сейчас мне для того, чтоб поменять шрифт всех вью элементов которые содержат текст понадобилось

- Скачать шрифт (calibril.ttf)
- Написать функцию

  public static void setFont(Context c, TextView name) {
      Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(), "fonts/calibril.ttf");
      name.setTypeface(font);
  }
- Добавить к каждому элементу метод в котором необходимо изменить шрифт

Можно ли как то на уровне приложения установить шрифт?

Я так понимаю, что я могу сделать так

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

и в теме для всей аппликации указать стиль шрифта, но какой тэг для этого существует?

Comment: Может переопределить нужные вьюхи(TextView,Button и.т.п), и переопределить в них назначение шрифта в конструкторе или каком-то методе жизненного цикла?

Comment: @jangorussia да, но это тоже не совсем удобно...

Answer (score 0):

Использую сторон. библиотеку на https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

Comment: Да я ее встречал раньше, но она я так понял не дает возможности установить стиль шрифта для всего приложения, она просто облегчает установку стиля в конкретное вью... или не так?